# How to handle onPress events for menus/lists? (Using React Native + TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a screen that renders a couple of  menu components and it looks all fine but for some reason my onPress functions never fires when I press the different items in the list.

I have a couple of questions;

1. So the first question is obvious, Why won't the `onItemPressHandler`function fire?
2. Secondly; Where would be the best way to put the onpress handler? On the menu components renderItem function or as part of the actual menuitem component

Here's my code:
    ....
    class ServicesContainer extends React.Component {

```
    onItemPressHandler = (item: object) => {
        console.log("====================================");
        console.log("onPagesMenuPress", item);
        console.log("====================================");
    }

    render() {

        const { pages, pagesStatus, services, servicesStatus } = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={[styles.backgroundPrimary]}>
                <Menu title={"Våra appar"} data={pages} status={pagesStatus} onItemPress={this.onItemPressHandler} />
                <Menu title={"Populära e-tjänster"} data={services} status={servicesStatus} onItemPress={this.someOtherHandler} />
            </View >
        );
    }
}
...
```

And here's the Menu component:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    View,
    ActivityIndicator,
    FlatList,
    Text,
} from "react-native";
import styles from "../../theme/styles";
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";

export interface Props {
    title: string;
    data: any;
    status: boolean;
    onItemPress: (item: any) => void;
}

const Menu = (props: Props) => {

    const { title, data, status, onItemPress } = props;

    const renderMenuItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return (<MenuItem title={item.title} key={index + Math.random()} onPress={onItemPress} />)
    }

    return (
        <View style={[styles.marginY, styles.marginX, styles.shadow, styles.backgroundWhite, styles.rounded]}>
            <Text style={[styles.label, styles.padding, styles.borderBottom]}>
                {title}
            </Text>

            {!status &&
                <ActivityIndicator style={[styles.margin]} />
            }

            {status &&
                <FlatList
                    scrollEnabled={false}
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={renderMenuItem}
                    style={styles.rounded}
                />
            }
        </View >

    );
};

export default Menu;
```

And last but not least here is the actual menuitem:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
} from "react-native";
import styles from "../../theme/styles";

export interface Props {
    title: string;
    key: number
    onItemPress: any;
}

const MenuItem = (title: string, key: number, onItemPress: any) => {

    const onPress = (e) => {
        console.log(onItemPress);
    };

    return (

        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.borderTop]} key={key} onPress={onPress}>
            <View style={styles.padding}>
                <Text style={[styles.h1]}>{title}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    );
};
export default MenuItem;
```

Comment: You don't have onPress event in MenuItem

Comment: I've updated the menuItem code above now, this in turn just generates new errors. Now I'm getting this: `Error: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, onPress}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: remoev key from TouchableOpacity

Comment: make sure data in flatlist is an array